# Speeding up double iterrows() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have several large data sets (~3000 rows, 100 columns) that I need to process with pandas. Each row represents a point on a map and there's a bunch of data associated with that point. I am doing spatial calculations (may introduce a few more variables in the future), so for each row I am only using the data from 1-4 columns. The issue is that I have to compare each row to every other row - essentially, I am trying to figure out spatial relationships between every point. At this stage in the project, I am doing calculations to determine how many points are inside a given radius for each point in the table. I have to do this 5 or 6 times (i.e. running the distance calculation function for multiple radius sizes.) This means that I end up with ~10-50 million calculations. It is slow. Very slow (like 9+ hours of computing time.)

After I run all these calculations, I need to append them as new columns in the original (very large) dataframe. Currently, I have been passing the entire dataframe to my function, which might further slow things down.

I know that many people are running this size of calculation on super computers or dedicated multicore units, but I would like to do what I can to optimize my code to run as efficiently as possible, regardless of the hardware.

I am currently using a double for loop with .iterrows(). I have stripped away as much of the unnecessary steps as possible. I may be able to pair down the dataframe into a subset, and then pass that to the function, and append the calculations to the original in another step, if that would help speed things up. I have also considered using .apply() to eliminate the outside loop (e.g. .apply() the inner loop to all rows in the dataframe...?)

Below, I have showed the functions that I am using. This is probably the simplest application that I have for this project... there are others that do more calculations/return pairs or groups of points based on certain spacial criteria, but this is the best example to show the basic idea of what I am doing.

```
# specify file to be read into pandas
df = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', low_memory = False)

# function to return distance between two points w/ (x,y) coordinates
def xy_distance_calc(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    return math.sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)

# function to calculate number of points inside a given radius for each point
def spacing_calc(data, rad_crit, col_x, col_y):
    count_list = list()
    df_list = pd.DataFrame()

    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        x_row_current = row[col_x]
        y_row_current = row[col_y]
        count = 0
        # dist_list = list()

        for index1, row1 in data.iterrows():
            x1 = row1[col_x]
            y1 = row1[col_y]
            dist = xy_distance_calc(x_row_current, x1, y_row_current, y1)

            if dist < rad_crit: 
                count += 1

            else:
                continue

        count_list.append(count)

    df_list = pd.DataFrame(data=count_list, columns = [str(rad_crit) + ' radius'])

    return df_list

# call the function for each radius in question, append new data

df_2640 = spacing_calc(df, 2640.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')

df = df.join(df_2640)

df_1320 = spacing_calc(df, 1320.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')
df = df.join(df_1320)

df_1155 = spacing_calc(df, 1155.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')
df = df.join(df_1155)

df_990 = spacing_calc(df, 990.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')
df = df.join(df_990)

df_660 = spacing_calc(df, 660.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')
df = df.join(df_660)

df_330 = spacing_calc(df, 330.0, 'MID_X', 'MID_Y')
df = df.join(df_330)


df.to_csv('spacing_calc_all.csv', index=None)
```

No errors, everything works, I just don't think it's as efficient as it could be.

Comment: Check out `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you loop too many times. At the very least, you should calculate a distance matrix and the count the how many points fall within a radius from that matrix. However, the fastest solution is to use numpy's vectorized functions, which are highly optimized C code.

As with most learning experiences, it's better to start with a small problem:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

# Create a dataframe with columns two MID_X and MID_Y assigned at random
>>> np.random.seed(42)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(1, 10, size=(5, 2)), columns=['MID_X', 'MID_Y'])
>>> df.index.name = 'PointID'

            MID_X     MID_Y
PointID                    
0        4.370861  9.556429
1        7.587945  6.387926
2        2.404168  2.403951
3        1.522753  8.795585
4        6.410035  7.372653

# Calculate the distance matrix
>>> cols = ['MID_X', 'MID_Y']
>>> d = distance_matrix(df[cols].values, df[cols].values)

array([[0.        , 4.51542241, 7.41793942, 2.94798323, 2.98782637],
        [4.51542241, 0.        , 6.53786001, 6.52559479, 1.53530446],
        [7.41793942, 6.53786001, 0.        , 6.4521226 , 6.38239593],
        [2.94798323, 6.52559479, 6.4521226 , 0.        , 5.09021286],
        [2.98782637, 1.53530446, 6.38239593, 5.09021286, 0.        ]])

# The radii for which you want to measure. They need to be raised 
# up 2 extra dimensions to prepare for array broadcasting later
>>> radii = np.array([3,6,9])[:, None, None]

array([[[3]],
       [[6]],
       [[9]]])

# Count how many points fall within a certain radius from another
# point using numpy's array broadcasting. `d < radii` will return
# an array of `True/False` and we can count the number of `True`
# by `sum` over the last axis.
#
# The distance between a point to itself is 0 and we don't want
# to count that hence the -1.
>>> count = (d < radii).sum(axis=-1) - 1

array([[2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 0, 2, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])

# Putting everything together for export
>>> result = pd.DataFrame(count, index=radii.flatten()).stack().to_frame('Count')
>>> result.index.names = ['Radius', 'PointID']

                Count
Radius PointID       
3      0            2
       1            1
       2            0
       3            1
       4            2
6      0            3
       1            2
       2            0
       3            2
       4            3
9      0            4
       1            4
       2            4
       3            4
       4            4
```

The final result means that within a radius of 3, point #0 has 2 neighbours, point #1 has 1 neighbour, point #2 has 0 neighbour and so on. Reshape and format the frame to your liking.

You shouldn't have a problem scaling this to thousands of points.